# ASP.NET pages not loading on IIS8 (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I am trying to set up my Windows Server 2012 to run an ASP.NET website. The website can serve html pages and .svc pages, but whenever I visit an .aspx page, it will simply time out.

> Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

If I would at least get some sort of error description, I could go from there, but I just get a timeout message, as if the server is completely unavailable, so I am stuck with this problem.

It seems the aspx pages are not loaded at all, since I've already tried drastic measures such as putting a "throw Exception" in the first line of Page_Load.

If I create a new site and put just an aspx page in there, it executes fine.

The Event Log is not showing anything in relation to this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Funky question I know, but this happens even to the best of us... Are you sure ASP and .NET framework are correctly installed ?

Comment: I am not sure it is correctly installed, but I am sure it is installed, because I can serve non-aspx pages that are still .NET 4.5: (.svc)

Comment: I just discovered, that if I create a new website in IIS, it will execute an aspx page.

Comment: If I create a new site and put a very simple application up there, it actually works, so I guess the problem must have a relation to my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new web site in IIS8 and pointing to the same folder made it work. Now the site is working fine and running code as normal.

My guess is, that if I created the website before installing all needed features, they were not part of that site. Now, after installing a new site, it contains all the current features.

It doesn't make TOO much sense, though, as the server had ASP.NET 4.5 from installation (it's Windows Server 2012).

Comment: With IIS you always have to make the steps in the right order to make sure that there is no cached configuration that is messing with you. When in doubt (after installing new components) consider rebuilding the application pool ( removing the application, deleting the application pool then recreate ) if possible.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and the above didn't work for me! :( What are the right order for the steps of adding a site?

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Web Platform Installer.

Now look for `IIS: ASP.NET 4.5`  and install that.

I had the same problem as everyone else and nothing worked until I did that.

There is a difference between installing dotNET on your computer/server and dotNET for IIS.

Comment: It says already installed for me, but still get the same error :(